# Send Email using SmtpClient: Prevent 3rd party software from adding Email signature

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtpclient

I'm using `SmtpClient` class in VB.Net to send Emails.

**The problem** is: In some cases, some 3rd party software add extra text to the Email.. e.g. Avast software adds the following signature:

> ---This email has been checked for viruses by Avast antivirus software.
>   https://www.avast.com/antivirus

The **reason** I want to prevent any extra text from being added to the Email is that I'm concerned about the length of the Email message.

Here's the code that I'm using now:

```
Private Sub SendEmail(LoginEmail As String, LoginPass As String, SmtpServer As String,
                      MailTo As List(Of String), Subject As String, MsgBody As String)
    Dim cred As New NetworkCredential(LoginEmail, LoginPass)
    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    client.Credentials = cred
    client.Port = 587
    client.Host = SmtpServer
    client.EnableSsl = True
    mail = New MailMessage()
    Try
        Dim mailFrom As New MailAddress(cred.UserName, "SENDER")
        mail.From = mailFrom

        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To MailTo.Count - 1
            mail.To.Add(MailTo(i))
        Next
        mail.Subject = Subject
        mail.Body = MsgBody
        mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
        mail.ReplyToList.Add(mailFrom)
        client.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So, **the question is:** is there a way to prevent any 3rd party software from adding extra text to my Email?

Comment: Good question. Although I guess it's a configuration of your Exchange/SMTP-Server what would make it a ServerFault question. But i'll try to get some evidence to this supposition

Comment: Or in your case it's an Avast option: http://www.getavast.net/support/remove-e-mail-signature

Comment: - It has nothing to do with the SMTP server. - Yes I know this option in Avast, and I can disable it for my PC, but what about after deploying the software to work on different PCs? let alone that Avast isn't the only software that does so

Comment: You could ask your users to turn it off... But that won't fly with them, it's good to have it on. You don't have control of this at all, besides there are numerous 3rd parties that do this how do you know which one?

Comment: Is the extra text added when the message is sent or when it is received?

Comment: @AndrewMorton when it's sent

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Perhaps you need to consider if an extra few hundred bytes is *really* a problem - it is the user's choice to include it. And should you be using `mail.To` or `mail.Bcc` - do you want all the recipients to know each other's email addresses?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was hoping to find a way to prevent this because I want to limit the length of the Email message to a maximum of 140 characters. You're right about using `Bcc` instead of `To` +1

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Then you will have to have your own SMTP server. If you happen to have your own website then it might come with a free SMTP server. You would have to devise some interface via a web service so that it is not blatantly abused, and limit the inevitable abuse attempts by truncating the message body at, say, 140 characters, and using all other content limitations than you can impose.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the email via a .php script which has been uploaded
on a webspace.
With this you prevent reeingeneering your software (this is quite simple) and
no one can change the email, also not anti virus software.